# How to move position of chart in excel by Java POI

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I want to add row in excel by java POI and I try with both `shiftRows()` function and `createRow()` function

[image]

both function can add row in excel but below chart position is remain and not move

I also like to move (shift down) the position of chart

I use poi version 3.9

Can anyone give me the advice or idea to move the position of that chart image

As the fact, the data range of chart also not changed. I need not only to move the position of charts but also need to increase the data range of chart

thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Really only move the positions of the charts? This will be easy. But as you see, the chart is broken also because of inserting a row within the chart's source data range.

Comment: Thanks for your point out.
Yes, the data range of chart also not changed.
I need not only to move the position of charts but also need to increase the data range of chart

Comment: Changing the data range of the chart will be complicated. Especially if the need is to do so for all chart types. Even if only for pie chart, then the problem is, that apache poi does not support pie charts by default until now. Only line charts and scatter charts are supported. But we could use the underlying objects. I will provide an example for pie charts this evening (Central European Time).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @AxelRichter
actually pai charts is not mandatory. if line chart also would OK. I can change pai charts with line chart in input excel file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shifting of the drawing anchors which determine the chart positions is possible. The method `void insertRowsShiftShapes(Sheet sheet, int startRow, int n)` does this for all drawing anchors which are affected of row inserting process into the sheet.

The correcting of the chart data ranges which are affected of the row inserting into the sheet is complicated as said already. It is not well tested and not ready yet. But I will provide it as a working draft. I hope it is a useful start point for further programming.

For running the code the `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is needed as mentioned in [apache poi FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)

A good resource for documentation of the ooxml-schema objects for me is [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/)

Examples: [CTTwoCellAnchor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/spreadsheetDrawing/CTTwoCellAnchor.java#CTTwoCellAnchor), [CTPieChart](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTPieChart.java#CTPieChart), [CTPieSer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTPieSer.java#CTPieSer)

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTTwoCellAnchor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer;

import java.util.List;

class InsertRowsAboveChart {

 //a method for shift rows and shift all anchors in drawing below the shifted rows
 private static void insertRowsShiftShapes(Sheet sheet, int startRow, int n) {
  java.util.List<CTTwoCellAnchor> drawingAnchors = ((XSSFDrawing)sheet.getDrawingPatriarch()).getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorList();
  for (CTTwoCellAnchor drawingAnchor : drawingAnchors) {
   int fromRow = drawingAnchor.getFrom().getRow();
   int toRow = drawingAnchor.getTo().getRow();
   if (fromRow >= startRow) {
    drawingAnchor.getFrom().setRow(fromRow + n);
    drawingAnchor.getTo().setRow(toRow + n);
   }
  }
  sheet.shiftRows(startRow, sheet.getLastRowNum(), n);
  correctDataRangesOfCharts(sheet, startRow, n);
 }

 //a method for correcting data ranges for charts which are affected of the shifted rows
 //!!working draft, not ready yet!!
 private static void correctDataRangesOfCharts(Sheet sheet, int startRow, int n) {
  java.util.List<XSSFChart> charts = ((XSSFDrawing)sheet.getDrawingPatriarch()).getCharts();
  for (XSSFChart chart : charts) {

   //pie charts
   java.util.List<CTPieChart> piecharts = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartList();
   for (CTPieChart piechart : piecharts) {
    java.util.List<CTPieSer> pieseries = piechart.getSerList();
    for (CTPieSer pieserie : pieseries) {
     boolean strRefchanged = false;
     if (pieserie.getCat().isSetMultiLvlStrRef()) {
      String strRef = pieserie.getCat().getMultiLvlStrRef().getF();
      //todo: this only corrects the end row of the ranges, should also correct start row if affected
      int strRefEndRow = Integer.parseInt(strRef.substring(strRef.lastIndexOf('$') + 1));
      if (strRefEndRow >= startRow) {
       strRef = strRef.substring(0, strRef.lastIndexOf('$') +1) + (strRefEndRow + n);    
       pieserie.getCat().getMultiLvlStrRef().setF(strRef);
       strRefchanged = true;
      }
     } else if (pieserie.getCat().isSetStrRef()) {
      String strRef = pieserie.getCat().getStrRef().getF();
      int strRefEndRow = Integer.parseInt(strRef.substring(strRef.lastIndexOf('$') + 1));
      if (strRefEndRow >= startRow) {
       strRef = strRef.substring(0, strRef.lastIndexOf('$') +1) + (strRefEndRow + n);    
       pieserie.getCat().getStrRef().setF(strRef);
       strRefchanged = true;
      }
     }
     if (strRefchanged) {
      String numRef = pieserie.getVal().getNumRef().getF();
      int numRefEndRow = Integer.parseInt(numRef.substring(numRef.lastIndexOf('$') + 1));
      if (numRefEndRow >= startRow) {
       numRef = numRef.substring(0, numRef.lastIndexOf('$') +1) + (numRefEndRow + n);    
       pieserie.getVal().getNumRef().setF(numRef);
      }
     }
    }
   }
   //pie charts end

  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("Workbook.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   //sheet.shiftRows(3, 5, 4);
   insertRowsShiftShapes(sheet, 2, 4);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   wb.close();

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !!!
It's really useful and make me sense for further programming

Comment: is there any possible way for HSSF type for your solution?
It's work well with XSSF type, but my target input file is *.xls file type

Comment: @AKZap: Sorry, but I will not bother myself with the old binary formats of Microsoft Office. Their formats are a pain and they are outdated since 2007. With the XML formats there is a chance for getting informations from the XML which the Office applications generate. The binary formats are painfully cryptical.